# Spark: Unable to Limit WebUI to localhost interface

Tags: apache-spark

I've search around the mailing list and SO spark tag, but it would seem that (nearly?) everyone has the opposite problem as mine. I made a stab at looking in the source for an answer, but I figured I might as well see if anyone else has run into the same problem as I.

I'm trying to limit my Master/Worker UI to run only on localhost. As it stands, I have the following two environment variables set in my spark-env.sh:

```
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1
```

and my slaves file contains one line: `127.0.0.1`

The problem is that when I run `start-all.sh`, I can `nmap` my box's public interface and get the following:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8081/tcp open  blackice-icecap
```

Furthermore, I can go to my box's public IP at port `8080` in my browser and get the master node's UI. The UI even reports that the URL/REST URLs to be `127.0.0.1`:

```
Spark Master at spark://127.0.0.1:7077
URL: spark://127.0.0.1:7077
REST URL: spark://127.0.0.1:6066 (cluster mode)
```

I'd rather not have spark available in any way to the outside world without an explicit SSH tunnel.

There are variables to do with setting the Web UI port, but I'm not concerned with the port, only the network interface to which the Web UI binds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

For spark 1.6, do the following:

- open core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/WebUI.scala
- find the line 'serverInfo = Some(startJettyServer("0.0.0.0", port,
  handlers, conf, name))'
- change "0.0.0.0" in the line  to some hostname you defined in LAN

After this you can access WebUI though LAN or a SSH-tunnel.